# "Microinteractions" or "Micro-interactions"?

Tags: grammar

I stumbled across the word "microinteractions", and can't understand how to correctly use it. Which one should be correct: "Microinteractions" or "Micro-interactions" or "Micro interactions"?

If there's already a similar thread to it, would appreciate it if you could redirect me.

Comment: How was it spelled where you stumbled across it?

Comment: This is a style convention. Whatever choice you make for prefixes, be consistent (e.g., don't combine "microinteractions," "macro evaluation," and "non-disruptive"). (Note, however, that some style guides always add a hyphen between vowels to avoid misreading: "micro-interactions," "pre-evaluate.")